# Typescript: How to use an enum to enforce that an array will contain specific values only from that enum?

Tags: angular, typescript, enums

I have an HTTP service in Angular that returns the accesses allowed for a particular user. The sample response is as follows:-

```
{
    "accessId": 4209318492034,
    "folderPath": "data/sample_folder/",
    "permissions": [
        "READ",
        "WRITE"
    ]
}
```

Specifically the permissions field is an array that will contain only the following strings, `"READ"`(compulsory) and `"WRITE"`(optional, may or may not be present).

I want to type this response using an interface, and for sake of enforcing the presence of only these strings in the permissions array, I created an Enum as follows:-

```
enum Permissions {
    READ = 'READ',
    WRITE = 'WRITE'
}
```

But using it in the interface for the response as follows does not work:-

```
export interface UserAccess {
    accessId: string;
    folderPath: string;
    permissions: Permissions[]
}
```

How do I enforce that the permissions array will contain values ONLY from the defined Permissions string enum?

Comment: TypeScript doesn’t do runtime things: you will need to perform the check at runtime yourself and throw an error if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't use enum, use type :

```
export type Permissions = 'READ'|'WRITE'

export interface UserAccess {
    accessId: string;
    folderPath: string;
    permissions: Permissions[]
}
```

Comment: This is much better than the previous solution! Marking as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following:

```js
export interface UserAccess {
  permissions:  (keyof typeof Permissions)[]
}
```

Note: TypeScript is just a compile-time concept and does not enforce anything at runtime.

Comment: This works, but I'd rather do it by enforcing an explicit error at runtime than this. Accepting because it is a valid solution.